# Prove that $2n+1 \leq 2^n$ for $n \geq 3$ using mathematical induction.

Tags: inequality, induction

Question:  $2n+1 \leq 2^n$, for all $n \geq 3$

I've tried:

Basis: $P(3) = 7 \leq 8 $, so basis step is valid

Pick an arbitrary value from the universe, $k \geq 3$

Inductive Step:  $2k + 1 \leq 2^k$

IH: $2(k+1) +1 \leq 2^{k+1}$

manipulation..., inequality proofs are troubling me so please correct the way I go about these.

$P(k+1) = 2k + 2 +1 \leq 2*2^k$

At this point, it is best to try to make the IH step look like the inductive step.
$=(2k+1) + 2 \leq 2*2^k$

$=(2k+1) \leq 2*2^k -2$

Now, I know I'm supposed to find another inequality to use the transitive property of inequalities.  However, at this step I'm completely lost.  I can do the following:

$=2k+1 \leq  2(2^k -1)$  and now I'm stuck..., What did I do wrong and which techniques should I keep in mind when doing these sorts of proofs?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know something about $2k + 1$, and want to relate it to $2(k + 1) + 1$. The easiest way to do this here is to simply expand, so that you can use the induction hypothesis directly:

\begin{align*}
2(k + 1) + 1 &= \Big(2k + 1\Big) + 2 \\
&\le 2^k + 2 \\
&\vdots \\
&\le 2^{k + 1}
\end{align*}

Now you need to fill in the vertical dots. One way to do this is to start with $2^{k + 1} = 2^k \cdot 2 = 2^k + 2^k$. Can you relate this to the line before the missing stuff?

Comment: $2^{k + 1} = 2^k \cdot 2 = 2^k + 2$ is wrong, should be $2^{k + 1} = 2^k \cdot 2 = 2^k + \color{red}{2^k}$

Comment: @CiaPan Yes, a typo. Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand.

I guess $(2k+1) + 2 \leq 2^k +2$, which leads to $(2k+1) + 2 \leq 2^k + 2 \leq 2^k + 2^k \leq 2*2^k \leq 2^{k+1}$   however, I don't understand how you can add $2^k$ in the second inequality.  Don't you have to add the same value to each side to keep the inequality true?

Comment: okay, I understand where the $2^k + 2^k$ comes from, it's a result of working backwards from $2^{k+1}$  obviously $2^k + 2^k$ is bigger than $2^k + 2$ and $2^k +2$ is obviously bigger than $(2k+1)+2$. Since $k \geq 3$.  This inequality is valid.

Comment: I'm choosing your answer because it's really clear about the flow of logic and the steps separated by line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

For the inductive step notice that:

$2(n+1)+1=(2n+1)+2\le2^{n}+2\le 2^{n}+2^{n}=2\cdot 2^{n}=2^{n+1}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Maybe it's nice to notice that $$2n+1 \leq 2^n \iff 2n \leq 2^n - 1 \iff 2n \leq 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + \cdots 1$$before doing the induction.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this method, the exponents n-1, n-2, eventually get down to n - n = 0, which makes that expression equal to 1 therefore canceling out the subtracted one.  How do we prove the induction hypothesis then?